# how to update component state when rerendering

Tags: reactjs

Hi I am trying to change the state of a component during the render. The state should change the classname depending on the list passed to it as props. I have tried but it does not seem to work. I can pass props but not change the state.

```
class Square extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {alive: true};
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }
    handleClick() {
        this.setState(state => ({
            alive: !state.alive
        }));
    };
    render() {
        return <div className = { this.state.alive ? "square--green" : "square--grey" } onClick = { this.handleClick } />;
    };
}

function SquareList(props) {
    const oxGrid = props.oxGrid;
    const listItems = [];
    oxGrid.forEach((item, i) => { 
        if(item === 'O'){ 
            listItems.push(<Square key= {i}/>)
        }
        else { 
            listItems.push(<Square key = {i} />) 
        }
    });
    return listItems;
};

let printer = (function () {
    let print = function (oXGrid) {
        return ReactDOM.render(<SquareList oxGrid ={oXGrid} />, grid);
    };
    return { print: print };
})();
```

Comment: React rerenders dom when components state is updated. what you are is not making sense?. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I want to render a list of Square components. These components should have different state  based on the array given as an argument to the SquareList function. So the array will have either O or X and I want to change the state accordingly to be either alive or not.

Comment: You can maintain state in Squarelist component by passing onClick handle to Square component as a prop and handle state directly in Squarelist component. so you dont need worry about state in Square components.

Comment: ok great, so I can't change state directly but I can do so indirectly via props. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made the following changes in `Square` and `SquareList` Component. You need to pass a prop item to the `Square` Component.

```
class Square extends React.PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        const isALive = this.props.item === 'O';
        this.state = {
            alive: isALive
        };
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }
    handleClick() {
        this.setState(state => ({
            alive: !state.alive
        }));
    };
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if(this.props.item !== nextProps.item) {
            this.setState({
                alive: nextProps.item === '0'
            });
        }
    }
    render() {
        return <div className = { this.state.alive ? "square--green" : "square--grey" } onClick = { this.handleClick } />;
    };
}

function SquareList(props) {
    const oxGrid = props.oxGrid;
    const listItems = oxGrid.map((item, i) => {
        return(
            <Square item={item} key= {i}/>
        )
    });
    return listItems;
};

let printer = (function () {
    let print = function (oXGrid) {
        return ReactDOM.render(<SquareList oxGrid ={oXGrid} />, grid);
    };
    return { print: print };
})();
```